# JSOUP is not rendering complete html

Tags: jsoup

I am trying to render a URL to read a few parameters by using JSOUP, but found that it is not rendering complete HTML.

Below is my code

```
Document doc=Jsoup.connect("http://www.svbcgold.com/").get();
System.out.println("HTML.."+doc.html());
```

In this its displaying only partial values but not all. In this page we are having some values like GOLD, SILVER but i was not able to see them in output, its showing output upto table only.

Requested you to please help me in this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your problem statement isn't entirely clear - please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: Is this question fully answered? Then please select the best fitting answer or post a follow up question in the comments (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

I think Jsoup didn't parse your entire document. That's why you don't able to get all the contents or someone's are missing. Try this :

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.svbcgold.com/").header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0").maxBodySize(0).timeout(0).get();
System.out.println("HTML.."+doc.html());
```

Hope your issue will solve.

Comment: The table containing the prices (`#LPriceTbl`) is generated and inserted using javascript, hence it is missing when parsing with jsoup (no javascript support). As expected your code is also missing the target information (the prices in the table).

Answer (score 1):

Using [`XMLHttpRequest`](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) the website requests the current prices with JavaScript.

Calling the following JavaScript code in the console (Chrome developer tools) replicates the background requests:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('post', 'http://www.svbcgold.com/LPriceSvbc.asmx/getSVBCPriceN', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "application/json");
xhr.send();
```

`xhr.response` then holds a JSON object, containing all the needed information:

```
"{"d":"[{\"BranchId\":9999,\"BranchDisplayName\":\"INTERNATIONAL\",\"BrPurityProductId\":9997,\"ProductDisplayName\":\"Gold\",\"PurityDisplayName\":\" \",\"ProductType\":\"U\",\"IsProductWeight\":0,\"LPrice\":\"1323.10\",\"TxtColor\":\"Black\"},{\"BranchId\":9999,\"BranchDisplayName\":\"INTERNATIONAL\",\"BrPurityProductId\":9998,\"ProductDisplayName\":\"Silver\",\"PurityDisplayName\":\"\",\"ProductType\":\"U\",\"IsProductWeight\":0,\"LPrice\":\"19.16\",\"TxtColor\":\"Black\"},{\"BranchId\":9999,\"BranchDisplayName\":\"INTERNATIONAL\",\"BrPurityProductId\":9999,\"ProductDisplayName\":\"USD/INR\",\"PurityDisplayName\":\" \",\"ProductType\":\"U\",\"IsProductWeight\":0,\"LPrice\":\"66.41\",\"TxtColor\":\"Black\"},{\"BranchId\":1,\"BranchDisplayName\":\"VISAKHAPATNAM\",\"BrPurityProductId\":1,\"ProductDisplayName\":\"Spot Gold 100g\",\"PurityDisplayName\":\"999\",\"ProductType\":\"G\",\"IsProductWeight\":0,\"LPrice\":\"315040\",\"TxtColor\":\"Black\"},{\"BranchId\":2,\"BranchDisplayName\":\"VIJAYAWADA\",\"BrPurityProductId\":2,\"ProductDisplayName\":\"Spot Gold 100g\",\"PurityDisplayName\":\"999\",\"ProductType\":\"G\",\"IsProductWeight\":0,\"LPrice\":\"315040\",\"TxtColor\":\"Black\"},{\"BranchId\":3,\"BranchDisplayName\":\"HYDERABAD\",\"BrPurityProductId\":3,\"ProductDisplayName\":\"Spot Gold 100g\",\"PurityDisplayName\":\"999\",\"ProductType\":\"G\",\"IsProductWeight\":0,\"LPrice\":\"315040\",\"TxtColor\":\"Black\"},{\"BranchId\":1,\"BranchDisplayName\":\"VISAKHAPATNAM\",\"BrPurityProductId\":1,\"ProductDisplayName\":\"Spot Silver 1kg\",\"PurityDisplayName\":\"999\",\"ProductType\":\"S\",\"IsProductWeight\":0,\"LPrice\":\"N/A\",\"TxtColor\":\"Red\"},{\"BranchId\":2,\"BranchDisplayName\":\"VIJAYAWADA\",\"BrPurityProductId\":2,\"ProductDisplayName\":\"Spot Silver 1kg\",\"PurityDisplayName\":\"999\",\"ProductType\":\"S\",\"IsProductWeight\":0,\"LPrice\":\"N/A\",\"TxtColor\":\"Red\"},{\"BranchId\":3,\"BranchDisplayName\":\"HYDERABAD\",\"BrPurityProductId\":3,\"ProductDisplayName\":\"Spot Silver 1kg\",\"PurityDisplayName\":\"999\",\"ProductType\":\"S\",\"IsProductWeight\":0,\"LPrice\":\"N/A\",\"TxtColor\":\"Red\"}]"}"
```

In Java we can use [`java.net.HttpURLConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) for the request and a JSON parser like [JSON.simple](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/) to parse the response.

**Example Java Code**

```
try {
    String url = "http://www.svbcgold.com/LPriceSvbc.asmx/getSVBCPriceN";
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();

    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
    con.setDoOutput(true);

    con.connect();
    OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    os.flush();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String response = in.readLine();
    in.close();

    // parse the response
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(response);
    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) new JSONParser().parse((String)jsonObject.get("d"));

    for (Object object : jsonArray) {
        jsonObject = (JSONObject)object;
        System.out.println(jsonObject.get("BranchDisplayName") + "\n\t" + jsonObject.get("ProductDisplayName") + " " + jsonObject.get("PurityDisplayName") + " " + jsonObject.get("LPrice"));
    }

} catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Output**

```
INTERNATIONAL
    Gold   1323.10
INTERNATIONAL
    Silver  19.16
INTERNATIONAL
    USD/INR   66.41
VISAKHAPATNAM
    Spot Gold 100g 999 315040
VIJAYAWADA
    Spot Gold 100g 999 315040
HYDERABAD
    Spot Gold 100g 999 315040
VISAKHAPATNAM
    Spot Silver 1kg 999 N/A
VIJAYAWADA
    Spot Silver 1kg 999 N/A
HYDERABAD
    Spot Silver 1kg 999 N/A
```

Answer (score 0):

Open this website in Chrome with your dev tools open. You will see that it makes asynchronous requests to load additional data after the page has been already rendered.

Jsoup only parses the initial response. It is not the right tool for JavaScript-driven websites. You need to use something like htmlunit possibly with PhantomJS.